# Combine two SQL Queries efficiently

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two Queries:

1)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, COUNT(supporter) AS done FROM Supports;
```

2)

```
SELECT supporter, COUNT(supporter) AS amount FROM Supports 
GROUP BY supporter ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1;
```

How can I efficiently combine them?

This is how the Table looks like:

```
+-----------------------------+
| id    | name    | supporter |
+-----------------------------+
|    1  | user1   |    sup1   |
|    2  | user1   |    sup2   |
|    3  | user1   |    NULL   |
|    4  | user2   |    sup1   |
|    5  | user2   |    sup3   |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: What should the output look like?  1 row with 3 columns?  3 rows with 1 column?  Something else?

Comment: 1 row with 4 columns (total, done, supporter, amount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the total, you'll have to use a subquery to combine into one query.  Include it in the FROM clause.

```
SELECT supporter, COUNT(supporter) AS amount, total, done 
FROM Supports,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, COUNT(supporter) AS done FROM Supports) totals
GROUP BY supporter
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! I liked how you just did one subquery rather than two :)
Your answer also has "DESC LIMIT 1" which the other answer probably forgot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Supports) as total,
  (SELECT COUNT(supporter) FROM Supports) as done,
  supporter, 
  COUNT(*) AS amount 
FROM Supports 
GROUP BY supporter 
ORDER BY amount;
```

Results looks like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e4ee/9

```
total  done  supporter   amount
5      4     sup3        1
5      4     sup2        1
5      4     NULL        1
5      4     sup1        2
```

Comment: I will use your query but with a "DESC LIMIT 1" at the end.
Unfortunately I can't mark it as correct answer because it misses that.
But I upvoted because I liked your approach to the answer and the sqlfiddle example :)

Comment: No worries @Bob. Glad it helped to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.total, a.done, b.supporter, b.amount 
      ( SELECT  COUNT(*) AS total, 
                COUNT(supporter) AS done
            FROM  Supports 
      ) AS a
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  supporter, 
                COUNT(supporter) AS amount
            FROM  Supports
            GROUP BY  supporter
            ORDER BY  amount DESC
            LIMIT  1 
      ) AS b;
```